# Archive extraction in Python extracts only part of one particular file

Tags: python, zip, extract

I'm working on a Python script in which I have to extract a certain archive and later on change the contents of a particular file I've extracted.
The extraction methods I've tried so far (shown below) have all resulted in the partial extraction of one particular file, while all the other files have been fully extracted.

Some information about the file that is being extracted partially:
a plain text file in the size of 18.8 kb (originally), extracted partially by my Python script to a file sized 6.6 kb.
**I've extracted the file manually using linux's built-in extraction and the text file was extracted successfully - so I've ruled out file corruption**

I've tried a few extraction methods:

**'file', in the code snippets below represents the name of the zip file. when trying each of the
following methods, I've made sure they all get the correct zip file**

```
shutil.unpack_archive(file, format="zip", extract_dir=extract_dir)
```

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(file,'r') as zf:
    zf.extractall(extract_dir)
```

```
os.system(unzip file -d extract_dir)
```

None of the above methods has worked.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What is the name of the file?

Comment: the name of the zip file is research.zip, the 'file' in the code snippets above is there just as a placeholder. the name of the text file is data.txt.  Do you think it is related to the names of the files?

Comment: If it had been research.gz for example, then yes.

Comment: What do you mean by "linux's built in extraction"? Is that on the same machine that you are trying these other means of extraction on? Can you provide a link to the .zip file?

Comment: when I right-click on the .zip file in linux, one of the options in the menu is 'extract here'. when I use it, the .zip extracts perfectly, including the 'data.txt' file. this is indeed the same machine. I can't provide a link to the .zip file as it contains sensitive information. @MarkAdler

Comment: It sounds like your zip file contains a feature that is supported by the Linux tools you are using, but is not supported by the python library. The zip file format has evolved over the years to support new features -- notably newer compression formats.  If you cannot post  the zip file, can you  upload the output from running `unzip -lv research.zip` in a terminal window on your Linux setup.

Comment: output: 18813  Defl:N     3126  83% ---- b8d01c87  txts/data.txt                                                         (partial because of data sensitivity). btw, when I run `os.system(unzip file -d extract_dir)` in the terminal, it extracts perfectly. it refuses to do so as part of the Python script for some reason. thanks for your help! @MarkAdler

Comment: So I understand, you're saying that all of the other files are being extracted correctly from this archive in all of the methods, but there is one file in the archive that is being correctly extracted in some cases, e.g. command line unzip, but that one file is only partially extracted in other caes, e.g. the same command run using Python's `os.system()`. Correct? Does the partially extracted file compare correctly to the fully extracted file, up to where it ends?

Comment: yes. that is correct. In my previous comment I meant 'when I run `unzip file -d extract_dir` in the terminal'. The partially extracted file is indeed matching to the fully extracted one, up to where the partially extracted file ends. I'd love to hear your ideas @MarkAdler @pmqs

Comment: Wait, so now you're saying that unzip in the terminal also fails to fully extract the file? You said before when you run unzip in the terminal, "it extracts perfectly".

Comment: Very sorry for the confusion. Terminal action are being executed perfectly, the .txt file is fully extracted. All tried extraction actions as part of the Python script extract the said .txt file partially. What do you think it could be?